# How do I implement a custom RazorViewEngine to search for views in two different ASP NET Core RazorPages locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

How can I redefine Razor views?
How would I like to do:
According to the standard, all views are stored in the Pages folder and, depending on the desired route, the desired directory is searched from the lower level (for example /Pages/Dictionary/Users) to the upper (up to the /Pages folder itself).
I want the OverridePages folder to be on the same level as the Pages folder and when searching for the required view, the search first went through the OverridePages/Default folder (Default can be changed to other directories) on the same principle from bottom to top as when searching in Pages. If the required view could not be found, then search as per the standard in the Pages folder.

I want to choose a full-fledged representation (@page is written at the beginning of the representation), and not a partial one. Ideas with searching for a partial representation in OverridePages/Default will not work.

I tried using IViewLocationExpander:

```
public class OverridePageViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        string rootPageDirectory = OrgFileDirectory.GetOrgDirectory(
            context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Items[ContextItemKey.OrgDirectory]
        );

        var extendedViewLocations = new List<string>(viewLocations);

        extendedViewLocations = extendedViewLocations.Select(location =>
        {
            if (location.Contains("/Pages"))
            {
                return location.Replace("/Pages", $"/OverridePages/{rootPageDirectory}");
            }
            else if (location.Contains("/Views"))
            {
                return location.Replace("/Views", $"/OverrideViews/{rootPageDirectory}");
            }
            else
            {
                return location;
            }
        }).ToList();

        var tmp = extendedViewLocations.Union(viewLocations);

        return extendedViewLocations.Union(viewLocations);
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context) { }

}
```

I have enabled OverridePageViewLocationExpander in the Program

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
 
builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new OverridePageViewLocationExpander());
});
```

The output is a list:

- "/OverridePages/Default/{0].cshtml"
- "/OverridePages/Default/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
- "/OverrideViews/Default/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
- "/Pages/{0}.cshtml"
- "/Pages/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
- "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"

In fact, the search root /Pages changes to /OverridePages/Default (but Default depends on some condition).

In the end, you should get a kind of redefinition of Razor pages. That is, if there is an "overridden version" of the view in the /OverridePages/Default folder, then take it, otherwise take the standard (basic) definition of the view.

Although the Index file is on the path /OverridePages/Default, the view is not taken from there. I think I need to implement a custom RazorViewEngine in some way.